# Saving a list email template: You're template isn't saved ... Attribute is not allowed

Tags: email-template

For those of you who are not familiar with the feature: in the Contact list view, there is a button 'Send List Email'. This allows you to send an email to a number of contacts.

While composing the email, you can also save it as a template, via the 'Insert, create, or update template' button. For one of my users, the 'Save as new template' button is not working.

A big, red, error message pops up, with a number of errors:

[image]

But he only entered a few characters (you can see them in the background), without any HTML tags. Other users do not have this problem. The user does not have or lack any distinguishing features as far as I can see (profile, permission sets).

What is going on here?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you check if the user typed in the text, or copy-pasted some text from elsewhere?

Comment: I've seen this error in the past and it was because there were hidden HTML values in the copied email from Microsoft Outlook that the Salesforce email editor window does not recognize.

Comment: We tried several times, just typing in one or two random words, starting anew, ... Try to save: error. Each and every time. But only this user.

Comment: @Swetha With my own eyes, I saw the user pop-up a new e-mail compose window, just type a few characters, click save and... error.

Comment: I googled some more, I found someone who had this problem while using a Chrome extension called Grammarly. I will check this with the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a browser plugin that apparently inserts all kind of (invisible) stuff that Salesforce does not like.

Disabling the plugin solved the problem.